LLM dataset tokenization issues for question answering fine tuning
I am using hugging face to fine tune a LLM for question answering. I am trying to figure out how to write a data preprocessing/tokenization function to use for this data set. I am using the nvidia/ChatQA-Training-Data dataset that can be found on hugging face here:https://huggingface.co/datasets/nvidia/ChatQA-Training-Data and I am trying to use this dataset to fine tune the "deepset/roberta-base-squad2" model for question answering that can be found here: https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2.
Here is my code so far:
import torch
from transformers import RobertaForQuestionAnswering, RobertaTokenizerFast, Trainer, TrainingArguments, DefaultDataCollator
from peft import LoraConfig
from datasets import load_dataset, DatasetDict
from transformers import pipeline

dataset = load_dataset("nvidia/ChatQA-Training-Data", "drop")
print(dataset)
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['messages', 'document', 'answers'],
        num_rows: 29195
    })
})

pretrained_model_name = "deepset/roberta-base-squad2"
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)
model = RobertaForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name)

def preprocess_function(examples):
    questions = [msg[0]['content'] for msg in examples['messages']]
    contexts = []
    for doc in examples['document']:
        if isinstance(doc, list):
            # Assuming the first element in the list is the main context string
            contexts.append(doc[0] if len(doc) > 0 else "")
        else:
            contexts.append(doc)
    
    # Extract the first element of each list in answers
    answers = [ans[0] for ans in examples['answers']]

    inputs = tokenizer(
        questions,
        contexts,
        max_length=512,
        truncation="only_second",
        return_overflowing_tokens=True,
        return_offsets_mapping=True,
        padding="max_length"
    )

    offset_mapping = inputs.pop("offset_mapping")
    start_positions = []
    end_positions = []

    for i, offset in enumerate(offset_mapping):
        answer = answers[i]  # Get the answer string
        context = contexts[i]  # Get the context string

        if not isinstance(context, str):
            raise ValueError(f"Expected string for context but got {type(context)}: {context}")

        # Find the start and end indices of the answer within the context
        start_idx = context.find(answer)
        if start_idx == -1:
            print("Error occurred in the following example:")
            print("Question:", questions[i])
            print("Context:", contexts[i])
            print("Answer:", answers[i])
            raise ValueError(f"Answer '{answer}' not found in context: {context}")
        
        end_idx = start_idx + len(answer) - 1

        # Map tokenized start and end indices to the original context
        start_positions.append(start_idx)
        end_positions.append(end_idx)

    inputs["start_positions"] = start_positions
    inputs["end_positions"] = end_positions
    return inputs

Here is where the function is called:
train_dataset = dataset["train"].map(preprocess_function, batched=True, remove_columns=dataset["train"].column_names)

And this is the error i get:
Map:   0%|                                                                            | 0/29195 [00:00<?, ? examples/s]
Error occurred in the following example:
Question: What happened first: intermittent invasion of Goryeo or fleeing of king to Ganghwa Island?
Context: From 1231, Goryeo was intermittently invaded by the Mongol Empire. During this time, Goryeo was controlled by a military regime led by the Choe family. In 1232 the government under the nominal king fled to Ganghwa Island, which Mongol horse riders were unable to land on, and resisted the Mongol invasion. Unfortunately because of its fragile foundation, Goryeo faced frequent rebellions. The 1258 rebellion resulted in the establishment of Ssangseong  and Dongnyeong Prefectures  by the Mongols. Unlike these rebels, the Sambyeolcho  were an organ of the military government. They were organized by the Choe family to maintain security. However, unlike the Choe private guards unit , the Sambyeolcho assumed public functions performed by police and combat forces, effectively replacing the Six Divisions of the military. In 1258, Choe Ui, the fourth of the Choe family, was overthrown by Kim Jun  using the Sambyeolcho. Kim Jun took a pro-Mongol policy and sent Crown Prince Wang Jeon to the Mongol Empire. At the same time, King Gojong and the crown prince approached the Mongols to restore power from Kim Jun. In 1268, however, Kim Jun was annihilated by the Sambyeolcho under the order of Im Yeon. The next year, Im Yeon's attempt to replace King Wonjong was reversed by the crown prince  with the help from the Mongol force. In 1270, Im Yeon's successor Im Yumu was killed by the pro-Mongol faction using the Sambyeolcho. It marked the end of the military regime.
Answer: intermittent invasion of Goryeo

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[78], line 1
----> 1 train_dataset = dataset["train"].map(preprocess_function, batched=True, remove_columns=dataset["train"].column_names)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\huggingface\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py:602, in transmit_tasks.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    600     self: "Dataset" = kwargs.pop("self")
    601 # apply actual function
--> 602 out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    603 datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    604 for dataset in datasets:
    605     # Remove task templates if a column mapping of the template is no longer valid

File ~\anaconda3\envs\huggingface\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py:567, in transmit_format.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    560 self_format = {
    561     "type": self._format_type,
    562     "format_kwargs": self._format_kwargs,
    563     "columns": self._format_columns,
    564     "output_all_columns": self._output_all_columns,
    565 }
    566 # apply actual function
--> 567 out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    568 datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    569 # re-apply format to the output

File ~\anaconda3\envs\huggingface\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py:3156, in Dataset.map(self, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, load_from_cache_file, cache_file_name, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, num_proc, suffix_template, new_fingerprint, desc)
   3150 if transformed_dataset is None:
   3151     with hf_tqdm(
   3152         unit=" examples",
   3153         total=pbar_total,
   3154         desc=desc or "Map",
   3155     ) as pbar:
-> 3156         for rank, done, content in Dataset._map_single(**dataset_kwargs):
   3157             if done:
   3158                 shards_done += 1

File ~\anaconda3\envs\huggingface\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py:3547, in Dataset._map_single(shard, function, with_indices, with_rank, input_columns, batched, batch_size, drop_last_batch, remove_columns, keep_in_memory, cache_file_name, writer_batch_size, features, disable_nullable, fn_kwargs, new_fingerprint, rank, offset)
   3543 indices = list(
   3544     range(*(slice(i, i + batch_size).indices(shard.num_rows)))
   3545 )  # Something simpler?
   3546 try:
-> 3547     batch = apply_function_on_filtered_inputs(
   3548         batch,
   3549         indices,
   3550         check_same_num_examples=len(shard.list_indexes()) > 0,
   3551         offset=offset,
   3552     )
   3553 except NumExamplesMismatchError:
   3554     raise DatasetTransformationNotAllowedError(
   3555         "Using `.map` in batched mode on a dataset with attached indexes is allowed only if it doesn't create or remove existing examples. You can first run `.drop_index() to remove your index and then re-add it."
   3556     ) from None

File ~\anaconda3\envs\huggingface\Lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py:3416, in Dataset._map_single.<locals>.apply_function_on_filtered_inputs(pa_inputs, indices, check_same_num_examples, offset)
   3414 if with_rank:
   3415     additional_args += (rank,)
-> 3416 processed_inputs = function(*fn_args, *additional_args, **fn_kwargs)
   3417 if isinstance(processed_inputs, LazyDict):
   3418     processed_inputs = {
   3419         k: v for k, v in processed_inputs.data.items() if k not in processed_inputs.keys_to_format
   3420     }

Cell In[77], line 42, in preprocess_function(examples)
     40     print("Context:", contexts[i])
     41     print("Answer:", answers[i])
---> 42     raise ValueError(f"Answer '{answer}' not found in context: {context}")
     44 end_idx = start_idx + len(answer) - 1
     46 # Map tokenized start and end indices to the original context

ValueError: Answer 'intermittent invasion of Goryeo' not found in context: From 1231, Goryeo was intermittently invaded by the Mongol Empire. During this time, Goryeo was controlled by a military regime led by the Choe family. In 1232 the government under the nominal king fled to Ganghwa Island, which Mongol horse riders were unable to land on, and resisted the Mongol invasion. Unfortunately because of its fragile foundation, Goryeo faced frequent rebellions. The 1258 rebellion resulted in the establishment of Ssangseong  and Dongnyeong Prefectures  by the Mongols. Unlike these rebels, the Sambyeolcho  were an organ of the military government. They were organized by the Choe family to maintain security. However, unlike the Choe private guards unit , the Sambyeolcho assumed public functions performed by police and combat forces, effectively replacing the Six Divisions of the military. In 1258, Choe Ui, the fourth of the Choe family, was overthrown by Kim Jun  using the Sambyeolcho. Kim Jun took a pro-Mongol policy and sent Crown Prince Wang Jeon to the Mongol Empire. At the same time, King Gojong and the crown prince approached the Mongols to restore power from Kim Jun. In 1268, however, Kim Jun was annihilated by the Sambyeolcho under the order of Im Yeon. The next year, Im Yeon's attempt to replace King Wonjong was reversed by the crown prince  with the help from the Mongol force. In 1270, Im Yeon's successor Im Yumu was killed by the pro-Mongol faction using the Sambyeolcho. It marked the end of the military regime.

I am new to fine tuning LLMs and the different tokenization processes for these models. Any direction will be helpful. Thank you.
